# Getting **failed to open stream: Connection refused** while accessing facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

I am creating a facebook application named pid or persianid.
When I am trying to read content from the Facebook Graph API I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: **failed to open stream: Connection refused**
```

This error also occurred while requesting an access token from Facebook.
When I use `file_get_content` without `@` it shows the same:

```
**failed to open stream: Connection refused**
```

What could be the reason that I get "Connection Refused"?

I am using sample code from the Facebook documentation.

Comment: "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" Is this the URL you're trying  to open or did you just cut out the access_token for demo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add the access Token after https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=
Without the access Token its not possible to get response from Graph API

Comment: Access Tocken is already there but  as follow                                                                    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

Comment: Thanks Mr Rajput. But I always add token but as its dynamic I haven,t added here in error description,But now Its working till I havent find reasn for that error. I want to use PHP SDK